# Raster to excel

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have a raster data of temperature and Precipitation of 30 years (30 raster layers for temp. and prep. respectively) and I need to convert each raster into csv file in R. I am new in R can anyone tell me how I convert tiff file into csv or excel file.

```
   library(raster)
   f <- system.file("D:/temp-data//data_range/bf.tif", 
   package="raster")
   x <-as.data.frame(r)
   x <- rasterToPoints(r)
   write.csv(x,"data.csv")
```

In 5th line of datatopoints they give error. can anyone reslove it.

Regards

Comment: (1) If you have an own file, don't use `system.file`. (2) We don't have access to your local file `bf.tif`, (3) It is unclear what `r` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try package **raster**. Instead of the system built-in file, use your tiff-file.

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
mat <- as(raster(f), "matrix")
write.csv(mat, file="data.csv")
```

**Edit:** Here another example, where we encode a matrix into a raster image and then back to a matrix:

```
## create some data
x <- seq(-1, 1, length.out=50)
z <- (x^2 %o% x^2)
range(z) # values from zero to one

## save it as tiff, here I use grey color but other colors are also possible
tiff("raster_grey.tif", width=50, height=50)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) # no margins
image(z, axes=FALSE, col=gray.colors(100, start=0, end=1))
dev.off()

## load the data and convert it to numbers
library(raster)
mat <- as(raster("raster_grey.tif"), "matrix")
View(mat)
write.csv(mat, file="data.csv")
```

We need of course a mapping which colors (or grey values) of the tiff match to which original values. Note also that tiff is a diverse class of formats, so you may first check if your tiff can at all be read by raster and if not, needs conversion.

Here the raster image (50 x 50 pixels, more is of course possible):

[image: raster image]

Comment: Sir this 3rd line is giving error and I try my best but didn't resolve it.-tpetzoldt

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Details depend on the kind and content of the raster file. Tiff files can be very different, and there is also question how translate raster intensity (i.e. color) into a useful scale.

Comment: Thank you so much for you r kind reply. I have edited my question. Can you see the code and please tell me what the problem in it . -tpetzoldt

Comment: See comments below your question.